# what vba code opens a .vsdx file in visio (running vba in excel)

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I want to assign a macro to a shape in Excel. When clicked will open a flow chart in Visio.  What coding will work similar to below which opens an Excel workbook, but instead would open a specific *.vsdx file?:

Workbooks.Open "ANALYSIS.XLS"

Answer (score 0):

Found help here:
[Open Visio Drawing using a Macro in Access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495483/open-visio-drawing-using-a-macro-in-access-2010)

This worked for me:

```
    Dim FName As String
    Dim VisioApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set VisioApp = GetObject(, "Visio.Application")
    If VisioApp Is Nothing Then
        Set VisioApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
        If VisioApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Can't connect to Visio"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    FName = "C:\Imaging\BLI-LOCF Flow Diagram.vsdx"
    VisioApp.documents.Open FName '
    VisioApp.Visible = True
```